# How to get Attribute value form Input field ? Selenium - Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

I'm trying to get attribute value from input field.
When i enter value "565656565" into the text box, i get something like in HTML:

```html
<input name = "placeHolder" id="$body_Txt">
> #shadow-root (user-agent)
   <div id="placeText" style="display">Enter Value </div>
   <div> 565656565 </div>
   </input>
```

Trying to get 565656565 text, So i create this:

```
getDriver().findelement(By.id("$body_Txt")).getAttribute("");
```

what should be in to the attribute ??
It's not working, Please help me as i'm unable to get it.

Thank you verify much.

Comment: It will not work for sure. `findelement(By.id(placeHolder))` here `placeholder` is not `id` but its `name` attribute value.

Comment: i  know it will not work, and I have tryied with Attribute im not sure what should put in attribute field to get the text. THanks

Answer (score 0):

why you want to use attribute? based on your provided example you can simply use xpath locator and getText() method:

```
getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id = '$body_Txt']/div[2]")).getText();
```